# How to import extensions of modules with Typescript, target: es6 and module: amd

Tags: javascript, typescript, jquery-ui, amd, knockout-validation

Specifically I'm trying to use knockout-validations with knockout and cannot get it to work. I had what seems to be the same problem when I attempted to add jQuery-UI to jQuery (months ago and gave up).

Knockout and jQuery work fine but I cannot get their extensions to show up.

I see a lot of people use require but it does not work while targeting es6, for kicks and giggles I changed the target to es5 but the imports didn't magically start working with imported them with require (one can dream!).

I have the type files for both installed via npm/node modules.

Our `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/build/",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

How we import both:

```
import * as ko from "knockout";
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

I've been told that importing this way prevents the extensions (e.g. `import: "knockout.validation";`) from being found but I'm not sure how else I can import it. The trouble with `import "knockout";` is that I need the `ko` handle.

Sincerely stumped. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: 50% of the internets bandwith is cat videos the other 50% is `rm -rf node_modules && npm -i`

Comment: @JoranBeasley haha, thank you but I don't think that's it but I still tried it  (`rd -r "node_modules"`, `npm install`). No dice.